# Problem running ASP.NET MVC in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am running my ASP.NET MVC application in IIS7 it gives the below error. Same thing works fine in IIS6

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Routing, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the MVC's routing module for the IIS7.  Merge this to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```